# classification of quasi-coherent sheaves on an affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, sheaf-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I am having trouble with Q. Liu's proof of the classification of quasi-coherent sheaves on an affine scheme. Specifically, I don't understand the first step of his argument (proposition 1.6., section 5.1).

He starts by saying that, by definition of quasi-coherent sheaf one always has an affine open and a sequence $$\mathcal{O}^{J}_V\to\mathcal{O}^{I}_V\xrightarrow{\alpha}\mathcal{F}_{|V} \to 0$$

He does not prove this claim, but this should be easy: by definition of quasi-coherent sheaf one has a generic open $U$ and an exact sequence as above, and then one can restrict to an affine open $V \subset U$ and check the exactness of the sequence on the stalks.

**question** What I don't understand is what he does next: he claims that considering the $\mathcal{O}_V(V)$-module $\operatorname{Im}\alpha_V$ and $\tilde{\operatorname{Im}\alpha_V}$, one has an exact sequence $$\mathcal{O}^{J}_V\to\mathcal{O}^{I}_V\xrightarrow{}\tilde{\operatorname{Im}\alpha_V}\to 0$$

> I do not see why he has that exact sequence.

First of all, by the right exactness one has $\operatorname{Im}\alpha_V \cong \mathcal{F}(V)$, so he might as well call it $\mathcal{F}(V)$.

Next, I think he uses, tacitly, the fact that $\mathcal{O}_V \cong \tilde{\mathcal{O}_V(V)}$, which can be proved by observing that $$\mathcal{O}_V(D(f)) \cong (\mathcal{O}_V)_f \cong \tilde{\mathcal{O}_V(V)}(D(f))$$ and hence they are isomorphic on stalks.

**specific question**

> I don't see how does he get the sequence
> $$\mathcal{O}^{J}_V(V)\to\mathcal{O}^{I}_V(V)\xrightarrow{}
>  \mathcal{F}(V)\to 0$$

because I know that exactness on the right of a sequence of sheaves does not in general imply that the sequence must be right exact on each open subset. So why can he infer this in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that the exponents here correspond to direct sums, not products. Let $\beta: O_V^{J} \rightarrow O_V^{I}$ map: then by the above exact sequence, $\alpha$ (or $\mathcal{F}_{|V}$) is the cokernel of $\beta$.

Let $M$ be the cokernel of $\beta(V): O_V^J(V) \rightarrow O_V^I(V)$: it’s an $O_V(V)$-module, and the sequence $$O_V^J(V) \overset{\beta(V)}{\rightarrow} O_V^I(V) \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$$ is exact.

Apply the tilde functor: $O_V^J(V)$ becomes $O_V^J$, $O_V^I(V)$ becomes $O_V^I$, and $\beta(V)$ becomes $\beta$, so that we have an exact sequence

$$O_V^J \overset{\beta}{\rightarrow} O_V^I \rightarrow \tilde{M} \rightarrow 0,$$

and thus $\tilde{M} \cong \mathcal{F}_{|V}$.

Comment: But why would $M \cong \mathcal{F}(V)$?

Comment: Your argument is correct, but what I don't understand is Liu's claim that the cokernel which you denote $M$ must be isomorphic to $\operatorname{Im}\alpha_V$

Comment: You have an exact sequence (by definition) $O_V^J(V) \rightarrow O_V^I(V) \rightarrow \mathrm{Im}\,\alpha_V \rightarrow 0$. Then apply the tilde functor.

Comment: ok, but $\operatorname{Im}\alpha_V$, the cockernel, is in general different from the sheafification $(\operatorname{Im}\alpha)^{+}(V)\cong \mathcal{F}_{|V}(V)$. This is the point that confuses me.

Comment: I am confused by the fact that a right exact sequence of sheaves $$\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{G}\to 0$$ does **not** in general give a right exact sequence  $$\mathcal{F}(V)\to \mathcal{G}(V)\to 0$$

Comment: And you’re right! But he’s not considering this right exact sequence. The image of $\alpha_V$ is just *the module such that we have an exact sequence of $O_V(V)$-modules* (so it doesn’t need to be equal to $\mathcal{F}(V)$). Then he takes the tilde it to get an exact sequence of sheaves.

Comment: Yes, but then he claims that $\tilde{M} \cong \tilde{\mathcal{F}(V)}$, so how does he prove it?

Comment: I agree with everything you have said until now, but Liu specifically claims the isomorphism $\tilde{M} \cong \tilde{\mathcal{F}(V)}$, this is the whole point of confusion to me.

Comment: Comparing the “original” exact sequence and the “tilde” exact sequence, it follows that $\tilde{M} \cong \mathcal{F}_{|V}$. *This* proves that $M=\mathcal{F}(V)$, which concludes.

Comment: Ah! beacause he first proves the isomorphism of sheaves and then is using that $\tilde{M}(V)\cong M$ by definition! Ok thank you very much.

Comment: Also, and this is a minor issue, because it does not affect the proof, is it really correct to say that $O_V^J(V) \rightarrow O_V^I(V) \rightarrow \mathrm{Im}\,\alpha_V \rightarrow 0$ is exact? I think there should be $\operatorname{coker}\beta_V$ instead of $\operatorname{Im}\alpha_V$, because how does one know a priori that $\operatorname{Im}\alpha_V \cong \operatorname{coker}\beta_V$?